# HTML table colspan vs CSS display:table

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a table with header captions and rows with columnar data that should be aligned with the header captions. Easy.

BUT, inside (or next-to) of every row must lie a dropdown div which provides related but non-tabular data for supplemental information.

Here is a picture of what I'm talking about: [image: table picture]

If I build this with an HTML table, I'll have to use `colspan` to create a single-celled row after every data row.
If I build this with CSS display:table, I could set the data rows as `display: table-cell` and the non-tabular data as divs with `display:block`, but is that syntactically OK?

**What is the most syntactically correct and/or reliable (ie. no hacks) way to build this?**

**What if IE8 is a requirement?**